# switching layouts in sapper?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I found a topic going on [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/823) but I can't figure out what to do precisely.

I have a portfolio section in my website and I need to put several components in each project pages (which are static). I am looking for a way to add my dedicated components (like a sub-nav or a "next project" button) at one place to avoid code duplication. The best way imo would have been to change the layout but it seems not possible yet.

I looked for a way to load a CSS file in each page to have common stylings but no success. If anyone has an idea on the best way to do that would be great !